# Styles marked "Always Hidden" keep appearing in the Styles Pane

Tags: microsoft-word, troubleshooting, microsoft-word-2010, styles, microsoft-word-2019

I have clients who have yet to master the idea of working with styles. Consequently, I create templates intended to expose them to only a few styles that I ever want them to see when using either the styles ribbon or the styles pane.

Among the styles I want to always hide from them are Table of Figures and TOCs 1-9.

No matter how many times I explicitly hide these styles via Manage Styles, the styles will not stay hidden. All it takes for the styles to show in the Styles Pane is to create or update a table of figures or a table of contents. The only control I seem to have is choosing what to show on the Styles Ribbon.

(a) Why do certain styles keep reappearing in the Styles pane while others remain hidden?

(b) If reappearing styles in the Styles Pane can be prevented, then what are the steps?

**Notes**

- Tested on a PC in Windows 10 Pro with Office 2019 and 2010.
- "Automatically Update" style is disabled (checked out).
- "Only in this document" is enabled (checked in).
- The hide styles problem is reproducible in documents that use only built-in styles, that have custom styles, or a mix of those.

Comment: Actually, it's not just ToCs that behave this way, otherwise I'd be inclined to blame it on something to do with field code behavior. I can also reproduce the problem by (for example) creating a custom style that does nothing more than shade text in a particular color.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old bug in Word that Microsoft has chosen to ignore.

See these posts:

- [Hidden TOC Styles reappear in the Style pane](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/hidden-toc-styles-reappear-in-the-style-pane/73d1de5a-f5a5-41bc-8d25-dd3243b65af4)
  Posted in 2013, last entry added in 2016.
- [Hidden styles unhide themselves in the Styles pane](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2a083b2a-2bce-40ed-9efc-d4befdec2d11/hidden-styles-unhide-themselves-in-the-styles-pane?forum=worddev)
  Posted in 2014.

The only workaround that was suggested was to add a VBA macro that will
re-hide the styles every time that the document is edited.
This might not be practical for you.

Comment: harrymc -- the links you posted were helpful, especially the second one because it provided a macro to undo (over and over again) what Word has wrought (over and over again). Will wait for a few days to see what other replies might filter in. In the meantime, for those reading this far, behavior is not not limited to built-in styles with field codes. It has happened with very simple custom styles, such as a character-only style to shade text in a color selected from the paint bucket.

Comment: If VBA is a possible solution, you may go this way. Note only that apparently, according to the second link, for example the TOC style returns after updating the Table of Contents, so it's not only at the beginning of the session that the styles need to be re-hidden.

Comment: See also my question here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/all-heading-styles-always-visible-in-quick-styles/f85dfa3e-ae7c-4ad8-a0e7-71b1141fd5c5.